# How to set a custom button click listener in a Custom Dialog from action bar?

Tags: android, xml

Ok, I can't figure this out .. 
Here is what I am trying to do:

I have an icon in action bar - when I click on it inflates a dialog with custom layout file. This layout has an `EditText` and a `Button`. The purpose of the whole thing is to write e message and then send it via the button when clicked. But when I click the button I get a `Nullpoint exception`..

Here is some code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();

    switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.action_logout:
            navigateToLogin();
            break;
        case R.id.action_edit_friends:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditFriendsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.action_message:
            Dialog messageDialog = new Dialog(this);
            messageDialog.setContentView(R.layout.message_bar);
            messageDialog.show();
            Button messageButton = (Button)messageDialog.findViewById(R.id.send_button);
            messageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    EditText messageText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_message);
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(messageText.getText())) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter a message first!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        String message = messageText.getText().toString();
                        Intent recipientsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RecipientsActivity.class);
                        recipientsIntent.putExtra("Text", message);
                        startActivity(recipientsIntent);
                    }
                }
            });
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

My custom layout file for the dialog is simply this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/structured_relative_interaction"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="bottom">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/send_button"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:hint="@string/send_message_hint"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
            android:maxLines="15"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/send_button"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/edit_text_message"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So what is it that I am doing wrong? I can't get around this issue and I've looked at other examples and read examples at the official documentation, but ... bummer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
EditText messageText = (EditText) messageDialog.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_message);
```

instead of

`EditText messageText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_message);`

Comment: Your edittext is part of custom dialog and not main layout. So you should call that custom dialog's findviewbyid like you have done for button.

Comment: Yes, that's it .. I don't know how I missed that :) spend 1 hour looking at it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Dialog` has also `setContentView(View)`, so you can inflate the view and passing to the `Dialog` the inflated view. You can also use the inflated view to find the view you need for the `onClickListener` purpose. My guess is that the view is not part of the Dialog's view hierarchy until it is visible at screen.

So I'll say

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.message_bar, null);
messageDialog.setContentView(view);
View messageButton = view.findViewById(R.id.send_button);
messageButton.setOnClickListener(...);
```